# Outdated name and broken logo in Data Explorer for Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)

Tags: bug, data-explorer, software-engineering-se

Programmers [recently changed name](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-site-name) to *Software Engineering*.

But this hasn't been reflected in the SEDE site switcher: it still shows the old name and the site logo is broken as shown on the screen shot:

> [image]

Comment: Turns out it's an old bug, SEDE is just not updated.